# One text input and a submit button in scala

Tags: forms, scala, textfield

I'm looking for a solution to accomplish the same thing as in this similar question:

[HTML forms with java Play Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019086/html-forms-with-java-play-framework-2)

But in Scala. Is there a way to do this? I just have one text field and a submit button. I want to get the value from the text field when pressing my button and pass this value to backend code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, set up the view & form the same way as in [HTML forms with java Play Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019086/html-forms-with-java-play-framework-2), and then put this in your controller.

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  case class Submission(value: String)
  val submissionForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "value" -> text
    )(Submission.apply)(Submission.unapply)
  )

  def myaction = Action { implicit request =>
    submissionForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        // do something with the bad form, like reshow the view
        Ok("got a bad form")
      },
      submission => {
        // do something with the submitted form
        Ok("got " + submission.value)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

[Play 2.1 Forms Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaForms)

Answer (score 5):

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  val submissionForm = Form(
    single("myvalue" -> text)
  )

  def myaction = TODO //as like @mbarlocker told before
}
```

On such a simple case of a single input, you don't have to use mapping in form definition and you don't have to use any template helper at the input. Template helpers are useful but in this case you get freedom over the layout, without writing a custom field constructor. For example, if you need to place the the submit button next to the input field, just write something like this:

```
@form(routes.Application.myaction, 'class -> "form-inline") {
        <input type="text" id="myvalue" name="myvalue" value="@submissionForm.data.get("myvalue")">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit :)">
    }
```

Comment: The "single" instead of "tuple" was very helpful, thanks.